# Wordpress: $wpdb prepare fails when using mysql DATE_FORMAT

Tags: wordpress

Today, I had a issue in $wpdb.

I used

```
$result = $wpdb->get_var( 
  $wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(report_date, '%d-%m-%Y') FROM table WHERE report_id = %d",
     $report_id 
   )
);
```

The above code not works because of %d in mysql `DATE_FORMAT`.

How i solved this issue in wordpress.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
$result = $wpdb->get_var( 
  $wpdb->prepare(
    "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(report_date, '%%d-%%m-%%Y') FROM table WHERE report_id = %d",
     $report_id 
   )
);
```

You need to escape the `%`'s by using `%%`